# Preposition 'de' + article dans le complément du nom

Tags: prépositions, articles, compléments, de

Il y a trois phrases:

1. une clé de porte
2. une clé d'une porte
3. une clé de la porte

J'ai entendu toutes les trois, mais je n'arrive pas à comprendre quand il faut mettre un article avant *une porte*. Est-ce que il y a un différence entre 1 et 2 ?

Comment: are you french or english?

Comment: I'm ukrainian :)

Comment: want the answer in english too?

Comment: It's seems that it is similar as in French, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> une clé de porte

cela veut dire que la clé ouvre une porte, mais on ne sait pas laquelle

---

> une clé d'un porte

Cette phrase n'a aucun sens car "porte" est un mot féminin, la phrase correcte est:

> Une clé *d'une* porte

Cette phrase signifie que c'est une clé d'une porte quelconque, on ne sait pas laquelle.

---

> une clé de la porte

Cette phrase signifie que la clé est une des clés qui peuvent ouvrir une certaine porte, si la phrase était

> *la* clé de la porte

Alors ça signifierait que c'est la seule clé pour la porte en question

Comment: donc, ca dépend sur qu'est-ce qu'on veut dire?

Comment: oui, c'est cela

Answer (score 0):

La phrase 2 n'est pas correcte. Elle n'a pas de sens.
La 1 signifie que cette clé ouvre une porte. On ne sait pas quelle porte.
La 3 signifie que c'est une clé de la porte indiquée ; de cette porte.