# When to use definite article after "de"?

Tags: prépositions

If I said "chicken leg" (or leg of chicken), I'm pretty sure it would be "cuisse de poulet", but if I said "majority of people" it would be "majorite des gens". So why doesn't the first phrase have a definite article (i.e cuisse du poulet), and what is the general rule?

Comment: Also relevant: https://french.stackexchange.com/q/18103/4082

Answer (score 2):

There won't be a definite article behind DE ever when it defines the quantity of something.

- Une cuisse de poulet
- Beaucoup de travail
- Un morceau de pain
- Un peu de tranquilité
- Une carafe d'eau

Here, DE is specifying what these quantities are about.
DE can therefore be translated as *of something*.

**But**, DE must be followed by a definite article when it precedes a word alone. For instance:

- De la tranquilité
- De l'eau
- De l'herbe
- Du travail (Why putting *du* here? you may ask. Well, the very thing to know is that DU is the combination of DE + LE. As *travail* is masculine, you won't say *de le travail*, you say *du*)